# Incorrect widget positioning in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

With a press of a button, I'm adding widgets to a `FloatLayout` inside of a `ScrollView`.
The code is a little too large so I include a Pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/nvkcd1NG)

So in that code, when I press a button (when there is some text in the lower `TextInput`), it creates an instance of `Message`, but seems to ignore all the placement and sizing instructions, putting it in the lower left corner with default size (100x100). Why is this happening? I've tried putting the `pos` attribute when creating an instance (e.g. `msg_stack.append(Message(pos=(50, 50))`), but it was ignored as well. I've also tried replacing the `FloatLayout` with a `RelativeLayout`, didn't work. Also, is `FloatLayout` what I need to stick to in this situation? Perhaps, a `GridLayout` could do me better?

Comment: Set positioning in the `Message()` itself, because in default, `Widget` takes `pos=[0,0]` and `size=[100,100]`. `msg_stack.append(Message(pos=[200,100]))` for example.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr, yea, I mentioned trying that, still the same :(

Comment: You should rewrite the program till it's small. Such mess pushes you into the maintenance hell. Don't write **anything** in `build` method, contain all logic inside widgets, and structure in kv file/string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is your `Message()` is at certain possition, but widgets inside are not - they're at the default position.

Simply, this will show you and the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html)(the red warning) explain, that you have to manage the positioning of the children alone, because it's not for example `BoxLayout`, but a simple `Widget` and it takes the default values for each `add_widget()`

```
<Message>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            size:self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

And set the position inside Message() when you add it to another widget `Message(pos=[200,200])`

Also, the code... that's pain, yes, but the biggest is using <tab> for indentation. It's fancy to make it work. Use 4 spaces instead, you'll spare yourself troubles in future. And avoid using function inside function if you don't need it to behave that way.

To fix it just replace every `self` with `root` in your Message() and position inner widgets manually with `pos=root.pos` and so on.